# How to convert an object to iterable (list)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to convert an object to an iterable.

I have the output of the format

```
>>>result[0]    
<Particle [0.015270307267929021, -0.0009933688866323714, -0.004208897534490854, -0.011275132115610775, 0.0029132053067140572, 0.005608170262839968, 0.0005401367846572976, -0.013393458586919493, 0.0003998091070805884, 0.0002900137732599478]>
```

The full code of the problem is

```
from fstpso import FuzzyPSO 

def example_fitness( particle ):
    return sum(map(lambda x: x**2, particle))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    dims = 10
    FP = FuzzyPSO()
    FP.set_search_space( [[-10, 10]]*dims ) 
    FP.set_fitness(example_fitness) 
    result =  FP.solve_with_fstpso()
    print "Best solution:", result[0]
    print "Whose fitness is:", result[1]
```

I want to use result[0] as the list.
[Source](https://github.com/aresio/fst-pso)

Comment: Your `result[0]` seem to be just one element `Particle` which looks to me contains a list inside. May I ask what is the data type of the `result[0]`? You could try `list(result[0])`. This should work most of the case, but this one may not since I see it as single element.

Comment: it is an object `fstpso.pso.Particle`

Comment: `list(result[0])` returns `TypeError: 'Particle' object is not iterable
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fstpso.pso.Particle` object is as follows:

```
class Particle(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.X = []
        self.V = []
        self.B = []
        self.MarkedForRestart = False
        self.CalculatedFitness = sys.float_info.max
        self.FitnessDevStandard = sys.float_info.max
        self.CalculatedBestFitness = sys.float_info.max
        self.SinceLastLocalUpdate = 0

        self.DerivativeFitness = 0
        self.MagnitudeMovement = 0
        self.DistanceFromBest = sys.float_info.max
        self.CognitiveFactor = 2.
        self.SocialFactor = 2.
        self.Inertia = 0.5

        # support for PPSO
        self.MaxSpeedMultiplier = .25
        self.MinSpeedMultiplier = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Particle %s>" % str(self.X)

    def __str__(self):
        return "\t".join(map(str, self.X))
```

From https://github.com/aresio/fst-pso/blob/master/fstpso/pso.py

What you want can be got with:

```
result[0].X
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment which states it's `fstpso.pso.Particle`, if you just call the following, you'll be able to use it as iterator without changing the original source code.

```
variable = result[0].X
for i in variable:
    print(i)
```

The original source code indicates the `__repr__()` function is just printing the `self.X` value, which is a list.

```
def __repr__(self):
return "<Particle %s>" % str(self.X)
```